# How does multiple inheritance works when using virtual base class?

Tags: c++

How does multiple inheritance works when using virtual base class?
How we know when and where we should use virtual base class?

For the following code, how do we obtain the output?

```
class A {
    public: 
        A() {
            cout<<"\t A";
        }
};

class B: public A {
    public:
        B() {
            cout<<"\t B";
        }
};

class C: public B {
    public:
        C() {
            cout<<"\t C";
        }
};

class D: virtual C {
    public:
        D() {
            cout<<"\t D";
        }
};

class E: virtual C, virtual D {
    public:
        E() {
            cout<<"\t E";
        }
};

class F: public B, virtual E {
    public:     
        F() {
            cout<<"\t F";
        }
};

int main() {
    F obj;
}
```

The output is:

```
     A       B       C       D       E       A       B       F
```

I get the warning
[Warning] direct base 'B' inaccessible in 'F' due to ambiguity [enabled by default]

How do I correct it??

Comment: I would first consider a redesign

Comment: What output do you want to get? How to "correct it" depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Virtual inheritance only applies from the level it is first introduced. Since neither `C` nor `D` inherit virtually, you still get duplicate bases and ambiguity, when you inherit from both (even virtually).

Comment: The compiler's warning is accurate. There's nothing to correct, presuming that you wish to keep this bizarre class hierarchy. The compiler is simply warning you that, unless you're careful, you could shoot yourself in the foot. As long as you avoiding shooting yourself in the foot, there won't be any problems.

Comment: By "correct it" I meant resolving the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

You've missed `virtual` in the following declarations (see comment of Story Teller) :

```
class B: public virtual A {...};
class C: public virtual B {...};
class F: public virtual B, virtual E {...};
```

Here is the demo: http://cpp.sh/6k2be